# GWT get variable dynamicly from object

Tags: gwt, variables, object

I have a few objects with variables in them for standard use. In GWT I would like to do the following:

```
public class myObject {
  protected TextBox textbox1 = new TextBox();
  protected TextBox textbox2 = new TextBox();
  protected TextBox textbox3 = new TextBox();
  protected TextBox textbox4 = new TextBox();

  // pass name of field: textbox1, textbox2... etc.
  public TextBox getMyTextbox(String fieldname) {
     return this.... [fieldname];
  }

}
```

The part return this... is what I really don't get. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: you would do something you don't really get? :) why would you do that? :) what is this.... [fieldname]?

Comment: @milan: functional I do the getMyTextbox but in my mind I don't know how to do it so I don't get it ;-).

Answer (score 0):

what do you find confusing here:

```
public TextBox getMyTextbox(String fieldname) {
     if ("textbox1".equals(fieldname) {
         return textbox1;
     } else if ("textbox2".equals(fieldname) {
         return textbox2;
     }  else if ("textbox3".equals(fieldname) {
         return textbox3;
     } else if ("textbox4".equals(fieldname) {
         return textbox4;
     }
}
```